# Using '&&' and '||' in a statement outside of condition in C

Tags: c, operators, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I'm working on a uni homework in C, I was given an already finished program to debug it and I've walked across this line of code

```
int main() {
FILE *personFile;

//...
//some code
//..

personFile && fclose(personFile);     //??
return 0;
}
```

Instead of

```
if (personFile != NULL) 
    fclose(personFile);
```

I think that `fclose(personFile)` 
never happens if `personFile` is NULL because of C quickly evaluating "conditions" and skipping second argument in && if the first one is false, but I'm not sure

Is this really how it works? And is this way of "cheating" conditons a bad practice or am I just lucky to never have seen something like this?

Comment: Yes. `&&` is a *short-circuit* operation (as well as `||`). Yet such a way of writing stuff is not very popular.

Comment: Someone's trying to be fancy. Just write it the verbose way unless you're golfing.

Comment: This is what gives C such a bad reputation, stupid little tricks like this that you have to know beforehand to understand without research. As the others said, just write it out with a one-line if statement and it'll be so much more readable.

Comment: @anonmess Hm. C has a bad reputation?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's known for being difficult to read, particularly for newcomers. While it isn't bad for more experienced programmers, it can be quite daunting for people just getting started, because of all the weird tricks and behaviors. Opinions are mixed though, I personally love C

Comment: @anonmess Really, most modern languages support this "style" of shorthand.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That may be, but any style guide would tell you that this is a terrible idea for clear, readable C coding.

Comment: Surely a sane compiler will generate the same code for this and for a simple `if` statement: https://godbolt.org/z/26X43J

Comment: @Carcigenicate The difference is that in modern language that support this, the statement is correctly typed and makes sense. In C it only works because the type system sucks and the compiler can’t enforce sane invariants.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It likely will generate the same code. In case like this, it's more for the programmer and anybody who might read the code. This is legal C, it's just not completely clear the intent for someone unfamiliar with the trick, while an `if` statement will be familiar to even the newest programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the operator `&&` uses short circuit evaluation (if the left operand is false/`0`, there is no way the expression could ever be true, so don't bother evaluating the right operand), this is just a check that the file pointer is non-`NULL` before calling `fclose` on it.

The `||` operator also uses short circuit evaluation, where if the left operand evaluates to non-zero, the entire expression is definitely true regardless of what the right operand is, so it is not evaluated.

> Is this really how it works? And is this way of "cheating" conditons a bad practice or am I just lucky to never have seen something like this?

There are plenty of "clever tricks" that are actually idiomatic C and wouldn't raise eyebrows during a code review; this one is not one of them to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this really how it works?

Yup

> And is this way of "cheating" conditons a bad practice or am I just lucky to never have seen something like this?

Using logical or conditional operators to control program flow *in place of a control structure* is not good practice, no.  That's not what those operators are for.  IOW, writing

```
some_condition && some_action();
```

*as a replacement for*

```
if ( some_condition )
  some_action();
```

is not good practice.

However, if you're wanting to evaluate a Boolean expression and assign the result somewhere, even if one of the conditions is a function call, then that's okay:

```
result = some_value && some_function();
```

IOW, we're *computing a value* using the `&&` operator, not controlling program flow (even though the `&&` affects whether or not `some_function()` gets called).

Same thing applies to the `?:` operator.  Writing

```
some_condition ? some_action() : some_other_action();
```

*as a replacement for*

```
if ( some_condition )
  some_action();
else
  some_other_action();
```

is bad practice.  However,

```
result = some_condition ? some_function() : some_other_function();
```

is okay, because we're not using it to control program flow, we're using it to compute a value.

Comment: *we're not using it to control program flow, we're using it to compute a value* - well, we are actually doing both in your examples

Comment: *IOW* stands for?

Comment: In Other Words ?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: yes, true, but the *primary* purpose is to compute the value.

Comment: @tilz0R: In Other Words